# How do I auto-strip auto-login parameters

Tags: php, joomla3.0, autologin

I have a php-site (Joomla) with auto-login parameters following the url like this:

www.mysite.com/article-title.html?username=flasp&password=encrypted

After users are auto-logged in through a newsletter they sometimes share the url and by doing so share their logged in access to the site.

Is there a way I can strip/remove the parameters shortly after the users are logged in?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe look for the equivalent of `document.replace()` that javascript offers.

Comment: Instead of giving password in url why dont you give them a temporary time based token which will expire within some time or the moment they log in. You can do that easily with a custom plugin.